# Python regex, capture groups that are not specific

Tags: python, regex

Consider the following example strings:

```
abc1235abc53abcXX

123abc098YXabc
```

I want to capture the groups that occur between the abc,

e.g. I should get the following groups:

```
1235, 53, XX
123, 098YX
```

I'm trying this regex, but somehow it does not capture the in-between text:

```
(abc(.*?))+
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I need to do it using regex, no string splitting, since I need to apply further rules on the captured groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`re.findall()`** approach with specific regex pattern:

```
import re

strings = ['abc1235abc53abcXX', '123abc098YXabc']
pat = re.compile(r'(?:abc|^)(.+?)(?=abc|$)')    # prepared pattern

for s in strings:
    items = pat.findall(s)
    print(items)
    # further processing
```

The output:

```
['1235', '53', 'XX']
['123', '098YX']
```

---

- `(?:abc|^)` - non-captured group to match either `abc` substring OR *start of the string* `^`
- `(.+?)` - captured group to match any character sequence as few times as possible
- `(?=abc|$)` - lookahead positive assertion, ensures that the previous matched item is followed by either `abc` sequence OR *end of the string* `$`

Answer (score 3):

Use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

```
import re

s = 'abc1235abc53abcXX'

re.split('abc', s)
# ['', '1235', '53', 'XX']
```

Note that you get an empty string, representing the match before the first 'abc'.

Comment: I guess, I simplified the question too much, I don't need to split it, I need to capture the group and then apply a further regex

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the string by `abc` and then remove the empty results by using `if` statement inside `list` comprehension as below:

```
[r for r in re.split('abc', s) if r]
```